# creating virtual directory programmatically iis7 in C#

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, iis-7

I would like to know if it possible to create a virtual directory directly to a site instead of creating a web application and then linking a virtual directory to that. I am using iis 7. thanks ! Src:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx
orginal post: https://serverfault.com/questions/328465/create-a-virtual-directory-for-a-website-programmatically-web-application/328466#328466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` and `Microsoft.Web.Management` .NET wrappers described [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/173/overview-of-mwa-and-mwm-for-iis/) to code up anything you need to do in IIS.